# cron job running mid file transfer

Tags: xml, ftp, cron

i have xml messages on a local server which are ftp´d over to the remote server and then a cron job runs a shell script every 5 minutes which looks for new xml messages, does some stuff and then give backs the log and error files. I wondering what would happen if the cron job kicks in while im in the middle of a file transfer and the script runs with only part of the xml message, what can i do to avoid this?

Comment: This is a very vague question and depends entirely on what `does some stuff` is.  Can you show us the shell script that runs out of cron?

Answer (score 0):

File transfer is not an atomic operation with respect to other file operations (such as open).  File rename is.  Transfer a temp file and then rename (rnfr/rnto) to the correct name.